# Number Theory: Divisibility on a set of consecutive integers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, divisibility, integers

Consider the set S of integers 1,2,...,n. Let 2$^k$ be the integer in S that is the highest power of 2. Prove that 2$^k$ is not a divisor of any other integer in S.
I don't want a complete proof here. I just want to know how to approach this problem, so that I can write a formal proof.

Comment: Suppose that $2^k$ does divide some $m \ne 2^k$ in this range. Then $m=2^kx$ for some integer $x \ge 2$. Show that this contradicts the definition of $k$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT:** What is the smallest natural number $x$ that is divisible by $2^k$, where $x > 2^k$?