# Number theory: Divisibility in block of any size

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, divisibility, integers

Prove that in any block of consecutive positive integers there is a *unique* integer divisible by a higher power of $2$ than any of the others.

1. I tried first doing this using the Fundamental theorem of Arithmetic but I was stuck in proving that the integer divisible by higher power of $2$ is unique. Can someone help me with this?
2. Then I tried to prove it by defining a set $S=\{2^k-n,2^k-n+1,\ldots,2^k-1,2^k,2^k+1,\ldots,2^k+n\}$, $n<2^k$ because the set must contain all positive integers. But I realized that this is not a general proof and applicable only if set is symmetric and has $2^k$. Can someone help me extend this proof for general case if possible?
3. Also can someone help me come to another proof of this statement. I think this problem uses results of this 
   [Number Theory: Divisibility on a set of consecutive integers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2897464/number-theory-divisibility-on-a-set-of-consecutive-integers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose there are two of them: $2^r a$ and $2^r b$ say with $a$ and $b$ odd and
$a<b$.
Then $b\ge a+2$, and the list of consecutive numbers also contains
$2^r(a+1)$. But $a+1$ is even.

Comment: Can you elaborate this? I think what you are trying to say is that if two numbers are divisible by highest power of 2 then it isn’t the highest power and we can find a new highest power of 2. @lordsharktheunknown

Comment: That's basically it. @Jimmy